# How to format multiplication table into 4 rows and columns respectively and test for even number multiplication table between 1 and 9?

Tags: java, oop

This is the code I atempted with the guide of external video which didnt cover expected output in terms of formatting

```
  public class Lab3Class {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int table = 1;

        while(table<10) {
             int i = 1;
             while(i<=10)
             {
                 System.out.println(table+ " * "+i+" = "+(table*i));
                 i++;
             }
            System.out.println("  ");
            table++;
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: What I mean is the code must compile to show (2x1=2, 2x2=4 etc ) for even numbers

Comment: And also 4 times table 6 times table as well as  8 times table for multiplication table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a check for even numbers i.e. `if (table % 2 == 0)`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int table = 1;

        while (table < 10) {
            if (table % 2 == 0) {
                int i = 1;
                while (i <= 10) {
                    System.out.println(table + " * " + i + " = " + (table * i));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            table++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternatively,** you can start table with `2` and increment it by 2 in each iteration as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int table = 2;

        while (table < 10) {
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= 10) {
                System.out.println(table + " * " + i + " = " + (table * i));
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            table += 2;
        }       
    }
}
```

If you need to print it in a tabular structure, you can write the loops as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int line = 1; line <= 10; line++) {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2) {
                System.out.print(i + "*" + line + "=" + (i * line) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2*1=2   4*1=4   6*1=6   8*1=8   10*1=10 
2*2=4   4*2=8   6*2=12  8*2=16  10*2=20 
2*3=6   4*3=12  6*3=18  8*3=24  10*3=30 
2*4=8   4*4=16  6*4=24  8*4=32  10*4=40 
2*5=10  4*5=20  6*5=30  8*5=40  10*5=50 
2*6=12  4*6=24  6*6=36  8*6=48  10*6=60 
2*7=14  4*7=28  6*7=42  8*7=56  10*7=70 
2*8=16  4*8=32  6*8=48  8*8=64  10*8=80 
2*9=18  4*9=36  6*9=54  8*9=72  10*9=90 
2*10=20 4*10=40 6*10=60 8*10=80 10*10=100
```

As you can see, it looks cleaner by using a `for` loop. However, I recommend you also practice it with a `while` loop. Once you gain more confidence, I also recommend you use [String::format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) or `System.out.printf` for better formatting.

This is a very small data set but if the dataset is huge, you can improve the performance by reducing the I/O operation. For this, you can append the result to a `StringBuilder` and print it just once at the end.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int line = 1; line <= 10; line++) {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2) {
                sb.append(i).append('*').append(line).append('=').append(i * line).append('\t');
            }
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm just being open to errors since neither I am a perfect programmer.

Comment: You are most welcome. I couldn't understand your comment clearly. Do you mean you are still facing some problem?

Comment: 2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
2 * 7 = 14
2 * 8 = 16
2 * 9 = 18
2 * 10 = 20
  
  
4 * 1 = 4
4 * 2 = 8
4 * 3 = 12
4 * 4 = 16
4 * 5 = 20
4 * 6 = 24
4 * 7 = 28
4 * 8 = 32
4 * 9 = 36
4 * 10 = 40
  
  
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18
6 * 4 = 24
6 * 5 = 30
6 * 6 = 36
6 * 7 = 42
6 * 8 = 48
6 * 9 = 54
6 * 10 = 60
  
  
8 * 1 = 8
8 * 2 = 16
8 * 3 = 24
8 * 4 = 32
8 * 5 = 40
8 * 6 = 48
8 * 7 = 56
8 * 8 = 64
8 * 9 = 72
8 * 10 = 80

Comment: This is what I meant by displaying multiplication of even numbers. and I got what I expected because of the condition . BtwI dont have enough practice to even solve a peanuts question

Comment: Let alone can I master this

Comment: Great! Wish you success!